# Why does the iPhone show the correct orientation of images whereas the desktop doesn't?

Tags: javascript, iphone, image, desktop, exif

I have a simple web app in which one takes a photo, which is converted to a base64 string in the client side, and that string is sent to a database and then displayed on the app by fetching it from the database. When I fetch the base64 string from the database, and display it in the app using `<img src="data:/png ...">`, it is rendered in the correct orientation on an iPhone but not on a desktop.

I have the impression that the base64 string doesn't contain any exif data about the image, so how does the browser know how to show the correct orientation in the iPhone but not on the desktop?

Moreover, suppose I do rotate the image, i.e., convert the base64 string to the rotated version of the base64 string based on the exif data, and then send it to the database, wouldn't I mess up the orientation on the iPhone then?

How to fix this conundrum?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the photo is rotated and has embedded metadata with the information about rotation. Some apps can read the metadata and rotate the photo. Whereas simply adding the photo as an `<img>` doesn't do that.

For rotating you will need a library that can extract that metadata.

[exifr](https://github.com/MikeKovarik/exifr) is fast at that and can handle hundreds of photos without crashing the browser or taking a long time :). Plus there's neat simple API and you feed it with pretty much anything -  element, URL, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, even base64 url or string and more.

```js
exifr.orientation(file).then(val => {
  console.log('orientation:', val)
})
```

This gives you an integer from 1 to 8 (learn more about [these values here](https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html)) and just apply `transform:rotate` to the image. Or you can redraw it using canvas (which is a bit more complex)